# Transparent background turns white after placing in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, transparency, file-placing

I removed the background of a picture in Photoshop and wanted to keep working on it in Illustrator, but when I placed the PNG the transparent background completely turned into white. I don't want to turn this picture into vector and remove white because that's not the effect I want in my design. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Here's a screenshot from Illustrator so you can see the problem
[image]

Comment: How did you move the image from PS to AI? What format is the raster image? Have you checked to make *certain* the background is transparent and not merely so faint it may be visibly unnoticeable?

Comment: I removed the background in PS, saved as PNG, opened Illustrator and choose File > Place and the transparent background turned into white, and yes the bg is completely transparent

Comment: @amenX is your Transparency box checked while exporting PNG from Photoshop?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue.

Comment: @amenX most probably, the PNG isn't exported with transparency. Here's a related question you may want to check: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/147709/png-is-saving-with-white-background/147744#147744

Comment: Oh okay, I see the problem now! I used Export for Web (Legacy) while saving this PNG, and it saved it as PNG-8 format. I checked the transparency box but when I placed it into Ai I had this issue. I saved it again with Export As in PS and that fixed it.

Thanks to both of you for telling me your thoughts!

Comment: @amenX note that PNG-8 also supports transparency. So I feel you didn't have checked the Transparency checkbox.